# UIViewContentModeRedraw vs setNeedsDisplay?

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't know the difference between setneedsdisplay and uiviewcontentmoderedraw, when would you use each, aren't they the exact same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different things.  `setNeedsDisplay` is a verb.  Use it to tell a view that the state of the stuff it's viewing has changed, so it should redraw (by calling its drawRect: method on the next iteration of the run loop).

`contentMode` is an attribute of a view.  It doesn't cause the view to do anything immediately. It specifies how the view handles its content relative to its size.  `UIViewContentModeRedraw` is a value that might be assigned to this property.  It means that the view will render size changes by causing itself to redraw (by invoking `setNeedsDisplay` on itself).

If you plan to animate alteration of your view's size, `UIViewContentModeRedraw` is an expensive choice because it will try to repeatedly redraw from scratch during the animation (rather than manipulating a bitmap copy).